# How to align the helperText to the far left in the TextField variant="outlined" in Material-UI for React?

Tags: material-ui

By default the helperText "Some important text" is not aligned to the far left. How can it be done?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `makeStyles` for your css and then apply your generated styles to the `className` prop inside of the  `FormHelperTextProps` prop from `TextField`.

```js
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  helperText: {
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        FormHelperTextProps={{
          className: classes.helperText
        }}
        label="Test"
        helperText="Helper text..."
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live demo:

[image: Edit how-to-align-the-helpertext-to-the-far-left-in-the-textfield-variant-outlined]

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update, I faced it in MUI5, and wanted to apply in ThemeProvider, so all my textfields get rid of that margin. For me it worked like this:

> ```
> import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
>
> export const theme = createTheme({
>   components: {
>     MuiTextField: {
>       defaultProps: {
>         FormHelperTextProps: {
>           style: {
>             marginLeft: '0',
>           },
>         },
>     },
>   },
> ```